# jQuery: An Extremely Bizarre Behavior with Arguments

Tags: jquery, if-statement, arguments

---

[update] My bad.. I didn't look through the codes properly..  I should have spotted such a small mistake.. What a shame.. I want to delete this question now but to no avail... It would be great if someone can help me delete this. I don't think such a stupid question deserve to be here.

---

I have this function:
    function magic(a,b,c){

```
  $("#a").on("mouseover", "."+a, function() { 

    $("#a").css("background", b).css("left", c);
    alert(a); 

    if(a="a"){
         b = "b";
         c = "10%";
    }else{
         b = "a";
         c = "0%";
    }
    alert(b);
    alert(c);

    $("#a").animate({
         "top":c
    },{
         duration:2000,
         complete:function(){
         $("."+a).addClass(b).removeClass(a);
         }
    });
  });
}
        After I execute it twice with different arguments `onLoad`        
  magic("a","black","10px");
  magic("b","red","2px");
```

the **first time** `mouseover` `.a`,
it should **`alert` "a", "b" then "10%",**
**and it does.**
However, the **second time** `mouseover`  the used-to-be-`.a` (which is `.b` now),
**instead of `alert` "b", "a", "0%",**
**bizarrely, it `alert` "b", then "b" again, then "10%".**
The conclusion I can give is that when going through
     if(a="a"){
                b = "b";
                c = "10%";
        }else{
                b = "a";
                c = "0%";
        }
**it treats `a` as it has been assigned `"a"` instead of `"b"`**
but back then it already `alert` "b"..
*(here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UqRdZ/)*
**I would appreciate if someone can explain it and provide a solution.**

Comment: not Bizarre at all, probably a typo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`

So

```
if(a == "a"){ ...
```

Comment: yeah... I'm retarded.. forgotten about the possibilities of having a small typo..

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a = "a"){
```

is not

```
if(a == "a"){
```

-- the former assigns `"a"` into a, then "returns" `a` as the expression value, the second does the comparison and returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

its not An Extremely Bizarre Behavior, you use assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operator `==` which always is `true`:

```
if(a == "a"){
     b = "b";
     c = "10%";
} else {
     b = "a";
     c = "0%";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a = "a"){..}
```

should be

```
if(a == "a"){...}
```

or

```
if(a === "a"){...}
```